# Avoid else if too much in fixedupdate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, optimization, frame-rate

I'm new to `Unity`.
Due to multiple else if (around 40), its decrease fps of my game.
How to optimize too many else if condition like this script?

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
    if (PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat == true)
    {
        offset.x = -5;
        offset.y = 14;
        offset.z = 6;
    }
    else if (PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat2 == true)
    {
        offset.x = -14;
        offset.y = 25.5f;
        offset.z = 6;
    }
    else if (PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat4 == true)
    {
        offset.x = -46;
    }
    else if (PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat5 == true)
    {
        offset.x = -62.7f;
        offset.y = 17.5f;
    }
    //else if { }
    //...
    //else if { }
```

Comment: First of all you should check if this block of code is really making your fps decreasing or if it is anything else. Cause 3 else-if are not a big no-no.

Comment: its not 3 else if in my script, i just post a few here. its like 40 else if. I am checking profiller and yeah its decrease my fps

Comment: Then we should know why are you using 40 else if. Probably your logical approach or the problem you are trying to solve with so many else-ifs

Comment: the statement is like if(bool1 == true) offset.x = 50 elseif(bool2 == true) offset.x = 30f. Until bool 40 using 40 elseif.

Comment: Just to test if this really is the problem: try removing (commenting out) most of your tests - does this speed up your app?

Comment: you could use a logic with array...see my answer

Answer (score 1):

One idea to avoid lot of if/else tests,

following your sample, you have only one (if/else if) true

so change your logic to use an index:

suppose you have:

```
PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat = 0 for PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat  = true
PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat = 1 for PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat1 = true
PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat = 2 for PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat2 = true
```

and so on..
my first idea was to use a dictionary, but you could use an array here

you create an array of vector3 :

```
public Vector3[] vector = new Vector3[50];
```

then you load all values (following your if/else if   tests):

```
vector[0] = new Vector3(-5f, 14f, 6f));
vector[1] = new Vector3(-14f, 25.5f, 6f));
vector[2] = new Vector3(-14f, float.NegativeInfinity, float.NegativeInfinity));
  :
  :
```

i use float.NegativeInfinity to indicate that i dont want to change the value.

finally you just have to test one value in general method

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    :
    :
    var v = vector[PisauScript.nonaktifkamera.manjat];
    
    if(!float.IsNegativeInfinity(v.x)) offset.x = v.x;
    if(!float.IsNegativeInfinity(v.y)) offset.y = v.y;
    if(!float.IsNegativeInfinity(v.z)) offset.z = v.z;
}
```

I have no tested errors..

I recommend you to use the [unity analyser](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/05/13/introducing-the-profile-analyzer/)... to see where you consume cpu

Because are you sure using lot of `if/else if` is really bad in performance?

Comment: Will traversing a dictionary not be far less efficient than three if/else blocks? Granted it might be a little neater, I only mention this as the question is _specifically_ about optimization

Comment: with three `if` no, with hundred maybe...i have no measured..In anyways its just a logic ..the real judge is to measure the lapse or to use the unity analyser. lot of people believe to write less lines of code gives performance....

Comment: i have easily changed to use an array. its always better than a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There is one blog that might be useful for you.

Link for blog: [https://medium.com/@janalmazora/how-to-prevent-using-if-else-statements-in-your-code-7e05e43afde#:~:text=Avoid%20using%20nested%20if%2Delse,get%20this%20(Code%201.4)](https://medium.com/@janalmazora/how-to-prevent-using-if-else-statements-in-your-code-7e05e43afde#:%7E:text=Avoid%20using%20nested%20if%2Delse,get%20this%20(Code%201.4)).

Also, you can try Branchless Programming if you really want to avoid if-else statements. This will increase fps for sure.

Link for Branchless programming: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVJ-mWWL7cE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `else if` only and not `if` then you only have one bool which is true. So you can make a list of `Vector3` (or `floats` this is your choice) and one `int` instead of `bools`.
Something Like this:

```
List<Vector3> vectors=new List<Vector3>(){new Vector3(-5f,14,6)};
int selectedvector=0;
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
    offset=vectors[selectedvector];
}
```